# Bind class to data object property in Vue.js and Slim

Tags: vue.js, slim-lang

I have the following `slim` template:

```
.dc-credit-card-label 'v-bind:class' => "{MyClass}"
  span.dc-credit-card--stars ••••
  span.dc-credit-card--stars ••••
  span.dc-credit-card--stars ••••
  span
    | {{ payment.last4 }}
```

So I am trying to set the MyClass = 'some-cool-class'
but this doesn't work

Is there any chance to do this?

Comment: Not 100% sure about the syntax but try,  `'v-bind:class' => "{MyClass: true}"`

Comment: Is this question about Sim template engine for Ruby?

Answer (score 0):

A comment from [this git issue](https://github.com/slim-template/slim/issues/792#issuecomment-391164414):

> You just use the directive tags like normal but make them slim syntax.

```
.signed-in v-if="user"
  = "Wecome, {{ user.name }}"
  a.sign-out-button v-on:click="signOut" Sign out
```

So, use it "normal":

```
.dc-credit-card-label :class="{MyClass}"
  span.dc-credit-card--stars ••••
  span.dc-credit-card--stars ••••
  span.dc-credit-card--stars ••••
  span
    | {{ payment.last4 }}
```